# In UWP app, why does Boost Asio socket always create Loopback connection?

Tags: c++, boost, uwp, boost-asio

I'm using Boost Asio socket in my UWP apps, checking in Resource Monitor I found that when I create Boost Asio socket, it always create two Loopbacks like this.

[image]

After lots of debugging, I found that it always create Loopback for UWP app in **socket_select_interrupter.ipp**

```
void socket_select_interrupter::open_descriptors()
{
  boost::system::error_code ec;
  socket_holder acceptor(socket_ops::socket(
        AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, ec));
  if (acceptor.get() == invalid_socket)
    boost::asio::detail::throw_error(ec, "socket_select_interrupter");

  int opt = 1;
  socket_ops::state_type acceptor_state = 0;
  socket_ops::setsockopt(acceptor.get(), acceptor_state,
      SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt), ec);

  using namespace std; // For memset.
  sockaddr_in4_type addr;
  std::size_t addr_len = sizeof(addr);
  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = socket_ops::host_to_network_long(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
  addr.sin_port = 0;
  if (socket_ops::bind(acceptor.get(), &addr,
        addr_len, ec) == socket_error_retval)
    boost::asio::detail::throw_error(ec, "socket_select_interrupter");

  if (socket_ops::getsockname(acceptor.get(), &addr,
        &addr_len, ec) == socket_error_retval)
    boost::asio::detail::throw_error(ec, "socket_select_interrupter");

  // Some broken firewalls on Windows will intermittently cause getsockname to
  // return 0.0.0.0 when the socket is actually bound to 127.0.0.1. We
  // explicitly specify the target address here to work around this problem.
  if (addr.sin_addr.s_addr == socket_ops::host_to_network_long(INADDR_ANY))
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = socket_ops::host_to_network_long(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
```

In Win32 apps, the loopback doesn't exist because Boost Asio uses I/O Completion port (**ASIO_HAS_IOCP**)

**basic_socket.hpp**

```
#if defined(BOOST_ASIO_WINDOWS_RUNTIME)
  detail::io_object_impl<
    detail::null_socket_service<Protocol>, Executor> impl_;
#elif defined(BOOST_ASIO_HAS_IOCP)
  // For Win32 app
  detail::io_object_impl<
    detail::win_iocp_socket_service<Protocol>, Executor> impl_;
#elif defined(BOOST_ASIO_HAS_IO_URING_AS_DEFAULT)
  detail::io_object_impl<
    detail::io_uring_socket_service<Protocol>, Executor> impl_;
#else
  // For UWP app
  detail::io_object_impl<
    detail::reactive_socket_service<Protocol>, Executor> impl_;
#endif
```

I have a deal with a partner that doesn't want the Loopback exists in my app, so I tried everything to disable or remove the Loopback, but no hope, I didn't find any Boost Asio documentation about it.

- What is the purpose of **socket_select_interrupter**?
- Why does Boost Asio socket always create Loopback in UWP app?
- Is there any way to disable or remove the Loopback?

Comment: Please don't post code as images.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into implementation details.

You might be able to check whether IOCP is enabled/can be enabled using the macros documented here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html#boost_asio.using.macros

Further more there are platform dependent implementation notes here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/implementation.html#boost_asio.overview.implementation.windows_nt__2000__xp__2003__vista__7__8__10_and_11

Specifically some of the implementation details depend on the use of a specific feature (like DNS resolution). You might be able to avoid them. UWP recommends a number of different API stacks besides Winsock here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/which-networking-technology